# How do I set up a connection to a Stonegate VPN in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, vpn

I have a single VPN connection plugin installed, `vpnc`. As far as I can see, it's not the thing I need for establishing a VPN connection to a Stonegate VPN gateway.

Is there a plugin available for that gateway? Which software should I use, or at least where should I start reading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like Stonegate runs on Red Hat. Your client may have a support contract that would allow them to ask Stonegate Support how to configure a linux client to a Stonegate server.

Alternatively, if you get the configuration file for the VPN client, you may be able to figure out the correct settings for the native Ubuntu vpn client.